# GPIO.add_event_detect() is detecting a false button press continuously

Tags: python-3.x, events, interrupt, gpio, raspberry-pi4

My question is: **GPIO.add_event_detect() is detecting a false Rising edge continuously in an infinite loop and running the call_back function() infinitely even though I do not press the push-button** connected to GPIO 25 even once But the call_back function() keeps executing.

Here is my code, where I want to call the call_back function x1() which contains the function WhatsApp(lat_o,long_o) only when the button is pressed but WhatsApp(lat_o,long_o) keeps executing without me pressing the button. Also, I put WhatsApp(lat_o,long_o) inside x1() to remove the problem of passing arguments to the call_back function.

```
#                           INTERRUPTS (NOT WORKING)

# Sample Coordinates
lat_o=33
long_o=72

# Import Libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

def x1(channel):
    WhatsApp(lat_o,long_o)

# Configure GPIO of Rpi
GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Use GPIO pin numbering
button1 = 25 # For WhatsApp

# Setup GPIO for Whatsapp
GPIO.setup(button1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN) # Set GPIO 25 (pin 22) to be an input pin for WhatsApp

# Detect button1-press
GPIO.add_event_detect(button1 ,GPIO.RISING, callback = x1)


try:  
    while True : pass  
except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

**Please help!**
I don't want to execute WhatsApp(lat_o,long_o) using Polling (i.e., using if-else in a while loop) in my Final Code for my Final Year Project because I want GPIO to detect button press continuously and using Polling here will drain a lot of power of my Raspberry Pi 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=134394) discussion on the raspsberrypi discussion

> A rising edge will be detected at approx. 1.25V. However, when the
> voltage lowers again and the input voltage drops below the 1.16V
> level, a stream of interrupts will start, and continue until the level
> is below 1.12V.
>
> This is most dramatic when slower rising or falling edges are present,
> as an example, when excessive anti-debounce measures have been taken.

This is the given solutuion

> In software, I use two other techniques to get rid of the false hits.
> First, after the edge has been recognized by the system, we don't know
> if it is the one we expect. By waiting for 5mSec, and then reading the
> input again but now with a Logic Level command, we can determine if
> the edge is indeed what we expect and we then avoid and discard all
> other (false) edges.

And finally the code for rising edge

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

Input_Sig = 23 # any plain GPIO pin
# if there is no external pull, use the internal one (pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(Input_Sig, GPIO.IN)


def interrupt_service_routine(Input_Sig):
    sleep(0.005) # edge debounce of 5mSec
    # only deal with valid edges
    if GPIO.input(Input_Sig) == 1:
        print("RISING")
    return

# define the event; bountime of 5mSec means that subsequent edges will be ignored for 5mSec
GPIO.add_event_detect(Input_Sig, GPIO.RISING, callback=interrupt_service_routine, bouncetime=5)


def main():

    try:
        while True:
            pass # your code

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        print("\nRelease the used pin(s)")
        GPIO.cleanup([Input_Sig])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @kinshukdua. By using the above modification (as suggested by you) in my code, I am able to correct Event-detection at the desired GPIO. So, your answer is 100% correct!

Comment: One question: Since there is an 'if' block inside the call_back function, won't it use the same power as polling or will the call_back function only be called at false/true rising edges and use less power than polling (i.e, if block inside while-loop instead of call_back function) ?

Comment: I just checked by putting a print("False RISING") above the if block inside the call_back function/interrupt_service_routine and observed that False RISING is being printed continuously almost like a while loop, which means that the interrupt_service_routine is being called continuously but if block deletes the false edges. My only concern is the power drainage of Raspberry Pi with respect to using a while loop in comparison with the continuous calling of the call_back function i.e., false edges. Can you please compare the two?